# Xcode 15 Simulator Compile with x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode-build-settings

After updating to Xcode 15, I'm no long able to run my code on a simulator. Currently I'm getting the error

`building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in object file (/{project path}/libs/IceLink/libFMIceLinkOpus.a[x86_64][15](bands.o)) built for 'iOS'`

When upgrading my Mac to the silicone chip, I did have similar issues where I had to insert this into my Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            # Needed for building for simulator on M1 Macs
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

Online there were similar errors with `arm64` architecture, which included updating the Excluded Architectures in the Build Settings. I figured I would do the same with `x86_64`

[image]

And after doing so I received another error when trying to run the code on a simulator

`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

Is this the correct path to go down, or should I look at another path? I'm not sure if adding `x86_64` to the Excluded Architectures is just leading me down a rabbit hole when I should be taking another route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is caused by Xcode 15's new linker,add the -ld64 flag under Other Linker Flags i solve this issue.

Comment: For me, adding that flag caused every library to fail to link and Xcode asked me whether I'd like to build for Rosetta (which I don't want).

Answer (score 2):

You're correct to worry that you're headed down a rabbit hole. The "excluded architectures" and the ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH settings were hacks that happened to work for a while. They never addressed the problem.

The fundamental issue is that the architecture is not a valid way to distinguish between device and simulator. For a long time people built "fat" (lipo) libraries based on this assumption, and it kind of worked, but was never actually supported. Then they added various configuration hacks to try to keep this approach working. In fairness, it was all we had since Apple didn't have a supported solution.

Apple finally does have a fully supported solution that works well. Your libFMIceLinkOpus library needs to be repackaged as an [xcframework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle) so that it can support both device and simulator. The specifics of how to do that depend on how your library is currently built and packaged.

Comment: Thank you for that information. So if libFmIceLinkOpus.a is a library from a third party, we will need them to repackage the library then?

Comment: Ideally, yes. It is possible in many cases to repackage other people's frameworks without the source code, but it is tricky work and not a great long-term solution. This has been hitting everyone, BTW, so it's no surprise it impacted you. While Apple announced the new tools, they never made clear exactly how to convert existing systems other than a list of "don't do the things you're doing." Building custom xcframework packaging systems has become my most common consulting job over the last year. I wish there were a simple "flip this setting in Xcode" answer I could give you or your vendor.